# Invalid token after upgrading Joomla to 3.5

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

After upgrading my site to J3.5, users can't login anymore.
They get the "invalid token" error.

I tried myself around 30 times and I also get the error, although I can login to the admin area.

I cleared Joomla cache, browser cache and truncated the `#__session` table.

But the problem persists.

This is critical! Users are paying to access certain areas of my site.

WHat more do I have to do to enable user login again????

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you cleared cookies?

Comment: Yes, I cleared cookies too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a core issue (our sites upgraded flawlessly) so should be an extension: read the apache error log and find out which is the offending one, rename its folder (i.e. plugins/system/yourstrangeplugin) and the frontend should load again. then go to the backend, disable the plugin, at that point you can restore its folder original name and update it.

in general, the developer will have issued an update by tomorrow if there are incompatibilities she'll know already.

Comment: @Ricardo Zorn thanks but where do I find the apache error log? In Cpanel error logs I can't find any errors related to this.

Comment: enable development debug level in the joomla options or on cpanel and see if it logs anything